# PrimeFaces TreeTable not responding to form submit

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, treetable

I'm trying to display values using primefaces Tree (and TreeTable, which would even be better, but the result is the same)

```
<h:form id="treeTableForm">
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{aircraftTypeHandler.tableSubmit}"
        update="@form" />
    <p:tree id="perfoTree" value="#{aircraftTypeHandler.perfosNode}"
        var="perfo" animate="true" style="min-width:300px;">
        <p:treeNode id="treeNode">
            <h:inputText value="#{perfo.type}" />
            <p:spacer width="20" height="0" />
            <h:inputText value="#{perfo.altitude}" />
            <p:spacer width="20" height="0" />
            <h:inputText value="#{perfo.mass}" />
            <p:spacer width="20" height="0" />
            <h:inputText value="#{perfo.distance}" />
            <p:spacer width="20" height="0" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
</h:form>
```

When pressing the commandButton, nothing happens.
When removing the  component, the backing bean method is correctly called.

Do you know why ?
How can I display data using "tree-like" components, and at the same time be able to interact with the data before sending it back to the backing bean ?

thanks

Comment: Maybe you can try to put your button outside of the form.

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing happens'? The AJAX request isn't sent? What exactly malfunctions in accordance with your expectations? Elaborate on it in a more developer-friendly way.

Comment: By the way, roughly the same setup can be found in [PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeSelectionSingle.jsf), which is working as expected.

Comment: The tree (or child elements) is probably causing validation/conversion to fail. Check your browser's developer console to check for warnings or place a `<h:messages/>` component on your page to catch errors

Comment: @kolossus : I put a <h:messages/ in my form but nothing is displayed when I press the button.

Comment: @skuntsel : "nothing happens" means that the log inside the listener method is not printed. I don't see any hint on what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by Ömer Faruk Almalı

Putting the button in an other form made the thing work. As for the explanation, I let you explain :)

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton id="singleBtn" value="Save" icon="ui-icon-save"
            update="@form :treeTableForm" process="@form :treeTableForm"
            actionListener="#{aircraftTypeHandler.tableSubmit}" />
</h:form>

<h:form id="treeTableForm">
        <p:treeTable id="perfosTreeTable"
            value="#{aircraftTypeHandler.perfosNode}" var="perfo"
            scrollable="true" scrollHeight="300">

            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Performances" />
            </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Perfo Type">
                <h:outputText value="#{perfo.type}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Altitude">
                <h:outputText value="#{perfo.altitude}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Mass">
                <h:outputText value="#{perfo.mass}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Distance">
                <p:inputText value="#{perfo.distance}"
                    rendered="#{perfo.distance != null}">
                    <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{aircraftTypeHandler.tableSubmit}" />
                </p:inputText>
            </p:column>
        </p:treeTable>
</h:form>
```